# Isotope script deletes some CSS rules?

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm developing a website and using the very nice [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html) script to create a filterable area with items.

I've set so the the items' background turns to red when you hover them, but strangely Isotope deletes the `hover` effect in **some** of them after some filtering.

You can see a sample of what I mean here: http://paragraphe.org/henpier/isotope_test/archive.html

Try to hover them: all seems all right. Then try to filter them several times, and suddenly some `hover` effects stop working...

Please guys, could you help me solve why this is happening?
Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was totally missing the important CSS rules that Isotope requiers, specially some `z-index` for the filtering part:

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/introduction.html#css

Thanks to David for pointing that out...

Answer (score 1):

Isotope will cause bubbling in the script - in reference to your hover effects bind them with using ON. http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$("p").on("hover", function(){
alert( $(this).text() );
});
```

Although - I see you are setting it via the css. - You can loop loop through the isotope element and append the class specifically to ensure it works. Or you could use the above hover function to append or remove the class.

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/extending-isotope.html

```
$('#container').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.element',
  itemPositionDataEnabled: true
})
// log position of each item
.find('.element').each(function(){
  var position = $(this).data('isotope-item-position');

//APPEND required class here. ensure its on the elements

  console.log('item position is x: ' + position.x + ', y: ' + position.y  );
});
```

Comment: _ Isotope will append and remove elements from the dom

Comment: ^ just edited the post - so you can also see how to get the position of the elements - its tricky with isotope - as the list elements merely translate, they don't change position like quicksand, so you can't just use $(li.gold').index()

Comment: By knowing the position of the items, you can acquire the coordinates

Comment: Thanks Bob, those hints are going to be useful. But I'm still struggling with the code..

Comment: Why does the class need to be so specific in terms of hover colors? - project small - I suggest you place data-attributes on the elements - this way the hover can still be applied without the need to retain class structure as such